# How can i use fragment xml tag in layout for another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-listfragment

i'm trying to do a three page which contains list fragment in an activity. All of the pages are fragment(from v4 support library) but i need list fragment inside them. When i tried that i have encountered a problem(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29473626/viewpager-gives-error-if-i-turn-page) then i have done some research and learned that there can not be fragment(i mean xml fragment tag not adding dynamically nested fragment) in fragment. But for instance, in the last android update of whatsapp there are three page in one activity and one of them has list fragment(chat list) so i wonder how whatsapp have done that? Thanks.

my xml layout which contains list fragment:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:text="Welcome to newsfeed" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/nfButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
    android:text="@string/signout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nfListFragment"
            android:name="com.comp.buzz.newsfeed.NFQuestionFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            tools:layout="@layout/item_question" />
        </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

onCreativeView method of main fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_newsfeed, container, false);
        Fragment fragment = new ListFragment();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.swipe_container, fragment).commit();
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest fragments with a few restrictions (according to the [doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)):

- Android 4.2 or higher
- You can nest them only programmatically

**Update 1**
Something like this should do the job:

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.add(R.id.swipe_container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: but i have a different layout, there are some textviews, buttons and a list fragment in the middle. so i must add it from xml i guess.

Comment: Can you describe your layout in depth?

Comment: i added it to my question it's the layout of one of the fragments of viewpager. so there must be that list fragment in my main fragment.

Comment: I am a little bit confused... Your question was "i wonder how whatsapp have done that?", right? I think the answers is that they had added it programmatically :)

Comment: yeah but the list fragment which can add only programmatically is between other things like buttons and textviews so how can i add it programmatically, also there is another tag on the fragment like swiperefreshlayout :S

Comment: i got it now. may you check my last update? it's like that now and after i go to page of that fragment it works and loads list fragment but if i go two page back and try to come back to that page it gives crash. i think it is because i am try to add it from code and from xml but if i remove it from xml i also cannot find the id of swipe_container..

Comment: I think you have to remove the ```<fragment>``` from the xml file. You shoudl add it only from the ```java``` code. The crash is possibly because you are trying to add it again... What is the crash? What exception do you get?

Comment: yea i agree you but if i remove the fragment from xml i also cannot add it from java code because there is no id (R.id.swipe_container) O.o

Comment: Just remove the fragment and leave the ```SwipeContainer```.

Comment: i did as you said now but there is no list now just refreshing screen because there is no fragment in swipecontainer :/

Comment: What is ```ListFragment```?? Is it your custom fragment? Android's ```ListFragment``` has no content. You have to create your class that extends ListFragment, instantiate it and then add it to the container.

Comment: i got it it works fine now thanks for your patience :)